# Cron refuses to reload nginx after certbot certificates renewal

Tags: nginx, certbot

**OS**: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
**Certbot**: certbot 1.11.0

I'm trying to use this cronjob:

```
{ certbot renew; nginx -t && service nginx reload; } &>/dev/null
```

`certbot renew` works OK - I see that the certificate is fresh. But nginx doesn't being reloaded.

If I enter `certbot renew; nginx -t && service nginx reload` in command line, everything works perfectly.

I have read that I can use certbot hooks. I wrote one in `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/deploy/001-restart-nginx.sh`, and here are the permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 88 root root 4096 Jan 31  2021 /etc/
drwxr-xr-x 9  root root 4096 Sep 20 19:37 /etc/letsencrypt/
drwxr-xr-x 5  root root 4096 Jan 29  2021 /etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/
drwxr-xr-x 2  root root 4096 May 17 06:10 /etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/deploy/
-rwxr-xr-x 1  root root 21   May 17 06:10 /etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/deploy/001-restart-nginx.sh
```

The content of `001-restart-nginx.sh` is:

```
service nginx reload
```

Even with the hook nginx still doesn't reload.

Comment: The user that CRON job runs under may not sufficient permissions to run `service` - you may need to adjust your `sudoers` and add `sudo` to the reload command.

Comment: If you're having trouble, why `/dev/null` any messages?  There might be an error msg which explains everything, which you're discarding.  Step 1 in debugging is to not suppress error msgs.  Are those curly brakets really valid? Keep it simple, get rid of them.  It is likely that only `root` can restart nginx, is this `root`'s cronjob?

Comment: @IVO, from what I can see in system.log, crontab works as **root**, there should be enough permissions.

Comment: @Don't Panic, oh right, weirdly I didn't even think about running without **/dev/null**. Removed the brackets, gonna test things again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRON does not populate the PATH environment variable - so you have to always provide the full path for every command. In your case these are:

1. the path to CertBot binary
2. the path to nginX binary
3. the path to the "service" BASH script

Comment: you was right: while `/usr/bin/`, where `certbot` is located, is in the cron `PATH`, `/usr/sbin/`, where `nginx` resides, is not. Changed crontab string to `certbot -q renew; /usr/sbin/nginx -tq && /usr/sbin/nginx -s reload;` Some time ago we moved away from writing full paths due to **CentOS** PHP binary located in some uncommon place, so the admin recommended to write simply `php` to run php scripts. That's why I messed with **nginx** calls. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not using paths in CRON jobs is often risky - you must always test them.